# Addition of two number,bt encounter with error

Tags: java

i am going to write my first java program:

```
public class Add{  
     public static void main(String args[])  {
          int a = 50;
          int b = 20;
          int C = a+ b;
          System.out.println("add is" +C);
     }
}
```

when i compilled ,compilation successful,but when run it it gives `error` as this:

```
E:\Work>javac Add.java  
E:\Work>java Add Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 
    at Add.main(Add.java:7)
```

This `error` is for every program I don't know why even when i want to print a hello word then same error,please help me instantly any one?

Comment: I am able to run your code. There is some problem with the way you are trying to execute.

Comment: It works fine for me.  Are you sure the code in your `Add.java` is exactly the same as you posted?

Comment: then what's the error tell me,how i will run it

Comment: OK, just a hunch, but what happens if you type `echo %CLASSPATH%` at the command line?

Comment: yes same just i copy ,paste.Again this error is for every program i write

Comment: After typing echo %CLASSPATH% it gives this C:/>program files/java/jdk 1.6.0/bin

Comment: now please tellme,what i do to execute my program

Comment: That should be "C:/>program files/java/jdk 1.6.0/bin/". You need the extra / on the end. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Does he also need `.` in his classpath?  (Sorry, I don't remember off the top of my head.)

Comment: even when i try to print "hello world" then also error occours,Exception in Thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFound Error:Hello

Comment: Is there really a `>` in the pathname when you display your `CLASSPATH`?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: That means what can i do for this,please please suggest me.

Comment: My classpath is just `.` (but I'm using JDK 7).  I'm not sure the "bin" is right for a classpath anyway; mine doesn't have any .jar files in it.....  Try `set CLASSPATH=.` and then compile and run again.

Comment: tell me how i run my program

Comment: `java Add`, which is what I think you were doing before.

Comment: now not any program working bakkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Well, try this book: http://myflex.org/books/java4kids/java4kids.htm (do not take its name for sarcasm please, it has not been meant like this). It's not the newest one but it'll give you some hints as how to start.

Comment: @user2807541 Sorry, I don't know what else to tell you.  I think you might have missed a step or mistyped something when you installed Java.  The whole problem seems really bizarre to me.

Comment: yep!!!!!!!!1 i solved it.Actually its environment variable problem ,i type simple command n its working